# C++ with XAML and UWP

Tags: c++, uwp-xaml

I used to code with C++ a long time ago and have decided to get back into it. With that being said I'm trying to teach myself some of the MS UWP type applications and I'm having difficulty finding any tutorials etc. that use C++ (instead of c#).

I've been experimenting with the panels and what not but I'm having a hard time simply displaying "flyouts". Here is my XAML:

```
  <StackPanel
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <CommandBar x:Name="Primary_Command_Add"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <CommandBar.Content>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Main_Menu"
                   Text="Main Menu"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   FontSize="18"
                   Margin="12"
                   IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
                   IsHoldingEnabled="False"
                   IsRightTapEnabled="False"
                   Tapped="Main_Menu_Tapped">

          <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <Flyout>
              <TextBlock Text="This should fly out" />
            </Flyout>

          </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        </TextBlock>
      </CommandBar.Content>

    </CommandBar>

  </StackPanel>
```

All I simply want to do is show the flyout when "Main Menu" is clicked on. In my .cpp I have:

```
void Program::MainPage::Main_Menu_Tapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{

}
```

Now I would think I would put something like "Flyoutbase.ShowFlyout" but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Should I just go and learn C#?

Comment: @AlbertoMiola 's comment is slightly wrong. C# is a *language*, and can be used with both WinForms and Windows Presentation Foundation (and maybe other things, like this UWP... it's been a few years since I've used these). WPF has used XAML for at least 6 or 8 years or so. It is *not* new. These are frameworks that execute on a Common Language Runtime. Presumably, managed C++ can work with them just as well as C#.

Comment: I guess I'll just learn c#; doesn't seem to be that bad. I was just looking at c++ as that's what I originally learned how to program on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show Flyout in C++, you can try this.

```
void MainPage::Main_Menu_Tapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    FlyoutBase::ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement ^)sender);
}
```

By the way, to access UI elements as variables, you can add `x:Name=""`.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="My_TextBlock"/>
```

C++:

```
void MainPage::Foo()
{
    My_TextBlock->Text = L"Hello, world!";
    // or My_TextBlock->Text = ref new Platform::String(L"Hello, world!");
}
```